# How to remove HTML element (select by class) of string by golang?

Tags: go

The example below:

```
content := "<p><a href=\"https://github.com/\">https://github.com/</a></p>
<div class=\"extract\">
   <p>hello1</p>
</div>
<div>hello2</div>
<div class=\"extract\"><p>hello3</p></div>"
```

I want to remove all "div" that has [class="extract"] include of all children elements too.

I want to get below result

```
content := "<p><a href=\"https://www.i-boss.co.kr/\">https://github.com/</a></p>
<div>hello2</div>"
```

I try to use regex, but it`s not working

Comment: Parse HTML with golang.org/x/net/html. Do **not** use a regexp as HTML is **not** a regular language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [goquery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) to parse and modify your HTML